# custom char to byte conversion in java

Tags: java, character-encoding, byte

Please help understand the lines(in bold) in the following piece of code -

```
public static byte[] stringToBytesUTFCustom(String str) {
 char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
 byte[] b = new byte[buffer.length << 1];
 for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
  int bpos = i << 1;
  b[bpos] = (byte) ((**buffer[i]&0xFF00)>>8**);
  b[bpos + 1] = (byte) (**buffer[i]&0x00FF**);
 }
 return b;
}
```

This is retrieved from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/java-best-practices-char-to-byte-and.html
What is the exact operation being performed in those particular lines?

Comment: that article has a very specific use case, which is to figure out how to turn characters into bytes (presumably for storage or data transmission) without doing any charset interpretation.  is that your intent, or are you intending to encode the data using a specific charset (a much more common scenario than the case in the article)?

Comment: i am trying to exact meaning and use of the statements in bold (line 6&7),without any specific used case in mind at the moment